# How to submit changes in LinqPad

Tags: c#, oracle, linqpad

I have a problem with committing changes in LinqPad. I am using Oracle database over IQ driver in LinqPad. I can retrieve data but I don't know how to submit changes to database.

I retrieve data from database:

```
 var items = Asyncqueue.Where(x => ids.Any(y=> y == x.Asyncqueueid));
 // then I have to fix data
```

I have tried to set submit action like this:

```
 Asyncqueue.SetSubmitAction(items, SubmitAction.Update);
```

Comment: Did you try SaveChanges();? What have you tried? Any errors?

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know where I can call SaveChanges or somethin similar.

Comment: Query your db, change value of record, call SaveChanges() ...

Comment: No problem, made it into an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Change Language in LINQPad to "C# Program" and use the following code

```
void Main()
{
    var p1 = Person.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
    p1.Name = "Test";
    SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: it should be SubmitChanges()

Comment: SubmitChanges for Linq-to-SQL and SaveChanges for Entity Framework.

Comment: You can also just change to "C# Statements" and leave out the `Main` function.

Comment: He's asking for IQ driver, so SubmitChanges is correct

Comment: No need for it to be switched to C# Program. C# Statement(s) works as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010176/1943 @Adrian's answer below.

Comment: what if I have a composit object because of a Join?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using an EF Context, then you need to call `SaveChanges()`

If you are using a Linq2Sql context, then you need to call `SubmitChanges()`